# Saving data for future use

Tags: plotting, save

I am trying to combine a few plots of complicated functions in different ranges into a single plot by using Show [ ] . Each of these plots take some hours to generate. Because of this I want to be able to, let's say, add some plots later in time, or modify the parameters in some of these plots later. I want to do it instead of having to run the entire thing again (which would take some days). Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: See [Iconize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize.html) and [DumpSave](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html).

Comment: add the option `PlotRange->All` in `Show`.

Comment: Have a look at `LocalSymbol`, e.g. `LocalSymbol["x"] = Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}]`. The data is stored in a file and recovered by evaluating `LocalSymbol["x"]`